# JS fs.createReadStream resize image before formData.append

Tags: javascript, node.js, sharp

I would like to resize and transform an image before adding to formData. I just tested a lot with e.g. the sharp library but I can't find a solution.

Some code:

```
formData.append('attachment', fs.createReadStream('sky.jpeg')); //This works fine
```

The formData accepts only JPEG, so if the user choose a png it should be transformed.

I tried this:

```
const trans = await sharp('png.png')
      .resize(1024)
      .toFormat("jpeg", { mozjpeg: true })
```

But the output is not be able to add to formData e.g.

```
formData.append('attachment', trans);
```

Comment: maybe only a workaround and not a great solution:
await sharp('png.png').resize(1024).toFormat('jpeg').toFile('temp/export1.jpeg'); 
    await sharp('pic.jpeg').resize(1024).toFormat('jpeg').toFile('temp/export2.jpeg'); 
    formData.append('attachment', fs.createReadStream('temp/export1.jpeg'));
    formData.append('attachment', fs.createReadStream('temp/export2.jpeg'));
    //delete file in temp folder after that